# How to format cat command as a table in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following code that parses XML to display the node value of each element in a file.

```
#Abbreviation - symbol
cat elements/*.xml |  egrep "<symbol>.*</symbol>" |sed -e "s/<symbol>\(.*\)<\/symbol>/\1/"|tr "|" " "

#Weight - atomic-weight
cat elements/*.xml |  egrep "<atomic-weight>.*</atomic-weight>" |sed -e "s/<atomic-weight>\(.*\)<\/atomic-weight>/\1/"|tr "|" " "

#Number atomic-number
cat elements/*.xml |  egrep "<atomic-number>.*</atomic-number>" |sed -e "s/<atomic-number>\(.*\)<\/atomic-number>/\1/"|tr "|" " " > number
```

How can I format the three of these outputs as a table instead of one huge sequential list?

Sample Data -

File1 -

```
  <symbol>Ag</symbol>
  <atomic-number>47</atomic-number>
  <atomic-weight>107.8682</atomic-weight>
```

File2 -

```
  <symbol>Ba</symbol>
  <atomic-number>56</atomic-number>
  <atomic-weight>137.327</atomic-weight>
```

Desired Output -

```
Symbol   Number   Weight
Ag       47       107.8682
Ba       56       137.327
```

Comment: My bad, i've added sample data and desired output

Comment: That's a grandiose [useless `(e)grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); the `tr` can also easily be folded into the `sed` script.

Comment: Nice, comments like these are what keep stack-overflow elitist. Thanks for the input though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%-9s %-9s %-9s\n' "Symbol" "Number" "Weight"

for F in *.xml
do
    symbol=$(grep -E "<symbol>.*</symbol>" "$F"               | sed -e "s/.*<symbol>\(.*\)<\/symbol>.*/\1/")
    number=$(grep -E "<atomic-number>.*</atomic-number>" "$F" | sed -e "s/.*<atomic-number>\(.*\)<\/atomic-number>.*/\1/")
    weight=$(grep -E "<atomic-weight>.*</atomic-weight>" "$F" | sed -e "s/.*<atomic-weight>\(.*\)<\/atomic-weight>.*/\1/")

    printf '%-9s %-9s %-9s\n' "$symbol" "$number" "$weight"
done
```

- `printf` allows you to format the width and alignment in that width of printed text (or number, or floats, ...).
- to avoid any interpretation of weight values (i.e. number of decimals for example), all values are printed as strings.
- for `printf`, `'%-9s'` means it will print the value using 9 chars wide, left aligned.  Without the `-`, it will align right.
- `printf` does not output a carriage return unless you tell it to, which explains the `\n`.
- I reused your `grep ... | sed ...` commands, but for 2 details.  **1** Used `grep -E` instead of `egrep`.  **2** Added `.*` at the beginning and end of your `sed` to eliminate prefixes or suffixes to the `<SOMETHING>` tags.

The output I get is:

```
$ ./so.bash 
Symbol    Number    Weight   
Ag        47        107.8682 
Ba        56        137.327
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you know is that is is valid XML, you would better use an XML parser. Such parsers come included, for instance, with *Ruby* or *Perl*.  This would allow you to also parse a file content which looks like

```
<atomic-weight>
  107.8682
</atomic-weight>
```

If however you can ensure that the input files follow **exactly** the format you have posted, you could do something like:

```
for file in File1 File2
do
  tr '<>' ' ' <$file | cut -d ' ' -f 3
done
```

If you need to format the data into columns at particular positions, you could do something like

```
for file in File1 File2
do
  printf ' put your format specification here ' $(tr '<>' ' ' <$file | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the input files are XML external general parsed entities,
and so concatenate to well-formed XML if wrapped in a root element,
you can use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) to process them in one go:

```
printf '<doc>%s</doc>\n' "$(cat file*.xml)" |
xmlstarlet select --template --var ofs="'$(printf "\t")'" \
    --value-of 'concat("Symbol", $ofs, "Number", $ofs, "Weight")' --nl \
    --match '*/*[position() mod 3 = 1]' --sort 'A:T:-' '.' \
    --value-of 'concat(., $ofs, following-sibling::*[1], $ofs, following-sibling::*[2])' --nl
```

- `printf`: wrap a document element around input
- `--var ofs` : define output field separator
- first `--value-of`: emit header
- list every 3rd element (i.e. symbol) sorted by symbol as
  `A`scending `T`ext
- to sort by atomic-number instead: `--sort 'A:N:-' 'following-sibling::*[1]'`

Output:

```
Symbol  Number  Weight
Ag      47      107.8682
Ba      56      137.327
```